# What is the elegant way to remove the blank space that sometimes shows up on the html tag?

Tags: html, css

So I'm analyzing my code with my dev tools and I see that the blank spaces at the top, left, and right belongs to the html tag. I need to make those blank spaces disappear.

Usually what I do in these cases is just to give this tag or some other tag inside the body a margin with negative values.

This works for the top and left margins, but makes the right margin easily overflow.

There must be a very elegant way of solving such a common issue. Maybe doing some trick with the border-box property, idk. Does anyone know the answer?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

By doing this the default margins and padding of your browser are removed.

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
```

Comment: That's not not good - this removes the default margins from *all* other elements too (for example headers, paragraphs etc., where a margin is usually desired to create distance to the next element). Better use `html, body { margin: 0; }`